# RaphaelJS stroke opacity

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I tried to set stroke `opacity` to 1 to avoid darken color on duplicate line. Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AG6k3/1/).

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);

paper.path('M10 20 L100 20');
paper.path('M50 20 L100 20');
```

I need to have same color every time.

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to `Robert Longson` - I got solution.

*Before:                                       After:*

[image: before] [image: after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not opacity, it's antialiasing you're encountering. Either

a) add 0.5 to the co-ordinates e.g.

```
paper.path('M10 20.5 L100 20.5');
paper.path('M50 20.5 L100 20.5');
```

or b) turn antialiasing off e.g. add this to your CSS

```
path {
    shape-rendering:crispEdges
}
```

Note that Raphael will stop you setting shape-rendering via the attr function so you have to work around that.

Comment: Adding 0.5 fixed problem, but I kinda need 2px lines, and after added `'stroke-width': '2'` I got nearly same problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sugaodax9u7q578/example.jpg - horizontal line is `stronger` because it have duplicate on top.

Comment: @Vaidas Use the CSS property, then.  However, be aware that it will make diagonal lines look more jagged.  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AG6k3/3/  Hover the mouse over the graph to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks guys, actually tried `shape-rendering:crispEdges` and it's just perfect. Too bad I didn't tried that in first try. Editing question.

Comment: Any solution for IE9? Just find out that IE not supporting `shape-rendering="crispEdges"`.